# Displaying a tooltip with an icon

Tags: winapi, tooltip

I want to display a `tooltip` with text and an *icon* when the *mouse pointer hovers* over a specific button. Below are two variants of this that I've seen, but I couldn't find information about the implementation.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC510746.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [TTM_SETTITLE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- custom Icons can be used in Windows XP SP2 and later.

Comment: Yep, looks like that's it, thanks. I would never thought to check a message named `TTM_SETTITLE` for a way to set an icon.

Answer (score 2):

@Edward Clements already told you an useful way, so you maybe know how to use it.
Anyway, I just add detailed code for refernce.

```
case WM_CREATE:

    hTip=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,TOOLTIPS_CLASS,NULL,0,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,
        hWnd,NULL,g_hInst,NULL);

    hBtn=CreateWindow("button","Test",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
        50,50,200,100,hWnd,(HMENU)0,g_hInst,NULL);

    ti.cbSize=sizeof(TOOLINFO);
    ti.uFlags=TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_IDISHWND;
    ti.hwnd=hWnd;
    ti.uId=(WPARAM)hBtn;
    ti.lpszText="This is a button";

    SendMessage(hTip,TTM_ADDTOOL,0,(LPARAM)(LPTOOLINFO)&ti);
    SendMessage(hTip, TTM_SETTITLE, (WPARAM)TTI_WARNING, (LPARAM)"Information");

    return 0;
```